# Unable to extract season from date attribute in shapefile

Tags: python, arcpy

I have a point shapefile with the following attributes:

```
FID    REPORT_DAT     Season
0       8/23/2018     
1       9/23/2020     
2       1/23/2020
```

The `REPORT_DAT` in esri has a data type of date but apparently it's a str when I print it out in the python console. I'm trying to fill in the Season field based on a specified date range using python. Here's what I have so far:

```
        import arcpy
from datetime import date, datetime


arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fc = r"C:\Users\RoadKill.shp"
#arcpy.AddField_management("roadkill", "Season", "TEXT", "", "", "20")  

seasons = {'spring':(datetime(2020,03,30), datetime(2020,04,13)),
           'summer':(datetime(2020,04,14), datetime(2020,10,31)),
           'autumn':(datetime(2020,11,01), datetime(2020,11,17)),
           'winter':(datetime(2018,11,17), datetime(2019,03,29))}


rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in rows:
    datetimeVal = row.getValue("REPORT_DAT")
    formattedTime = datetime.strftime(datetimeVal, "%Y/%m/%d")
    datetime = datetime.strptime(formattedTime, "%Y/%m/%d").date()
    print(datetime, type(datetime))
    

    def get_season(datetime):
        print(datetime, type(datetime))
        for season,(season_start, season_end) in seasons.items():
            if datetime>=season_start and datetime<= season_end:
                return season


    arcpy.CalculateField_management("roadkill", "Season", get_season("REPORT_DAT"), "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

My print statement prints out:

```
(datetime.date(2018, 8, 23), <type 'datetime.date'>)
('REPORT_DAT', <type 'str'>)
```

I thought I converted the date to the right format above and passed it to the `REPORT_DAT` field but I'm still getting this error:

```
         line 19, in get_season
                   if datetime>=season_start and datetime<= season_end:
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to str
```

Any suggestions on how to properly convert my date field?

Answer (score 3):

You must convert your dates before any comparison. You can try this:

```
# First harmonize your seasons dates by replacing date by datetime

seasons = {'spring':(datetime(2020,03,30), datetime(2020,04,13)),
           'summer':(datetime(2020,04,14), datetime(2020,10,31)),
           'autumn':(datetime(2020,11,01), datetime(2020,11,17)),
           'winter':(datetime(2020,11,17), datetime(2020,03,29))}

def date_conversion(my_date):
    values = my_date.split('/')
    year, month, day = int(values[0]), int(values[1]), int(values[2])
    return datetime(year, month, day)

# rename the variable date by my_date
def get_season(my_date):
    my_date = date_conversion(my_date)
    for season, (season_start, season_end) in seasons.items():
        # Refine your comparison
        if season_start <= my_date <= season_end:
            # You should return season, not seasons
            return season
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried adding this but get an error :`year, month, day = int(val[2]), int(val[0]), int(val[1]) NameError: global name 'val' is not defined'` 
Then I tried changing val to values but get this error: 
`year, month, day = int(values[2]), int(values[0]), int(values[1])IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: can you add a `print(my_date)` just before `values` and show the result?

Comment: When I added print(my_date) it printed my Report_Dat field which is good. Then I got the error again that the list index is out of range. 
 `year, month, day = int(values[2]), int(values[0]), int(values[1])
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I need to see the result of the `print` to see the format of the date. From there I would know how to detect the error

Comment: I was able to reformat that date field correctly and it prints out my dates in this format `2020/08/17`. I updated my code above if you would take a look. Still getting the bug stated in my original question `can't compare datetime.datetime to st` in my get_season though..

Comment: @JNN The error is pretty self-explanatory. It tells us that one of the variables is in datetime format and the other is a string. To solve this problem you have to convert the string format to datetime format before comparing the two. For that, you have to know how your string is formatted. In order for us to help you convert your date correctly you have to show us how it is formatted. So when I ask you to show us the print result, what I want to see is what your console displays.

Comment: So, in your function `get_season`, add `print(formattedTime, type(formattedTime))` and show us the full result which is displayed in your console.

Comment: Okay, when I add the print statement I get `('REPORT_DAT', <type 'str'>)`. When I add this same print statement after the search cursor I get: `('2018/08/23', <type 'str'>)`. So it's still a string.. See edits above in question.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using an update cursor to solve my issue.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        myDate = datetime.strptime(datetime.strftime(row[0], "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d/%Y")
        if (myDate >= datetime.strptime("03/30/2020", "%m/%d/%Y") and myDate <= datetime.strptime("04/13/2020", "%m/%d/%Y")):
            row[1] = "SPRING"
        elif (myDate >= datetime.strptime("04/14/2020", "%m/%d/%Y")and myDate <= datetime.strptime("10/31/2020", "%m/%d/%Y")):
            row[1] = "SUMMER"
        elif (myDate >= datetime.strptime("02/06/2020", "%m/%d/%Y") and myDate <= datetime.strptime("01/10/2020", "%m/%d/%Y")):
            row[1] = "FALL"
        elif (myDate >= datetime.strptime("02/10/2020", "%m/%d/%Y")):
            row[1] = "WINTER"

        cursor.updateRow(row)
```